# ObjectContext tracking changes in Entity Framwwork

Tags: entity-framework

I need to know if in my objectContext any changes have been made (include attached and detached entities). Should I loop over all my entities in all my ObjectSets and check their EntityState or is there a shorter way?

Comment: objectContext  can't track changes of detached objects

Answer (score 1):

`Detached` entities are detached = context doesn't know about them and it cannot track its changes. You cannot loop through your ObjectSets - it would load whole your database to your application! If you want to know state of your entities tracked by the context use:

```
var entries = context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(~EntityState.Detached);
```

This will get your collection of `ObjectStateEntry` where each entry represents single tracked entity or independent association.

Comment: What does the ~ mean? why only EntityState.Detached?

Comment: `~EntityState.Detached` in this case means all states except `EntityState.Detached`

Comment: And also, how do I recognize if there was entity detached?

Comment: Did you at least try it? What are you waiting for? Yes it returns unchanged as well, you can modify the condition if you don't want them. Detached entities are detached = context doesn't know about them. You can try to handle `ObjectStateManagerChanged` event. Perhaps it will inform you about detaching.

Comment: Of course I tried it.  And it didn't react for detached that why I asked.  I will try ObjectStateManagerChanged.