# Entity Framework - Delete entity in Oracle 10g { Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object}

Tags: entity-framework, oracle10g

I try use Repository pattern in Entity Framework on Oracle 10g.  I simplified my code:

Here is SQL code:

```
-- Create table
create table TESTTABLE
(
  MODULE_UNIQUE_ID VARCHAR2(32) not null,
  PANEL_STATUS     VARCHAR2(8) not null
)
tablespace SYSTEM
  pctfree 10
  pctused 40
  initrans 1
  maxtrans 255
  storage
  (
    initial 64K
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );
-- Create/Recreate primary, unique and foreign key constraints 
alter table TESTTABLE
  add constraint TESTTABLE_PK_01 unique (MODULE_UNIQUE_ID)
  using index 
  tablespace SYSTEM
  pctfree 10
  initrans 2
  maxtrans 255
  storage
  (
    initial 64K
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );
```

I create simple repository class:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity, TCtx>
{
    TCtx Session { get;}
    void Add(TEntity entity);
    void AddOrAttach(TEntity entity);
    void Delete(TEntity entity);
    int Save();
    TEntity SelectByKey(string colName, string key);
}

public class Repository<TEntity, TCtx> : IRepository<TEntity, TCtx>,
    IDisposable
    where TEntity : EntityObject
    where TCtx : ObjectContext
{
    #region Private fields

    private TCtx _ctx;
    private string _keyProperty = "ID";

    public int Save()
    {
        return _ctx.SaveChanges();
    }

   public TEntity SelectByKey(string colName, string key)
    {
        KeyProperty = colName;

        // First we define the parameter that we are going to use the clause.
        var xParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), typeof(TEntity).Name);
        MemberExpression leftExpr = Expression.Property(xParam, KeyProperty);
        Expression rightExpr = Expression.Constant(key);
        BinaryExpression binaryExpr = Expression.Equal(leftExpr, rightExpr);

        //Create Lambda Expression for the selection
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> lambdaExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>
            (binaryExpr, new ParameterExpression[] { xParam });

        //Searching ....
        //IList<TEntity> resultCollection = ((IRepository<TEntity, TCtx>)this).SelectAll(new Specification<TEntity>(lambdaExpr));

        //if (null != resultCollection && resultCollection.Count() > 0)
        //{
        //    //return valid single result
        //    return resultCollection.First();
        //}
        //return null;

        return ((IRepository<TEntity, TCtx>) this)
            .SelectAll(new Specification<TEntity>(lambdaExpr)).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        _ctx.DeleteObject(entity);

    }

 }
```

Problem is first I select some entity and then I want delete. 
Select works against Oracle DB good. Problem is update or delete command.

```
   var _repo = new Repository<TESTTABLE, Entities>(
            new Entities(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Entities"]
                          .ConnectionString));

    var obj = _repo.SelectByKey("MODULE_UNIQUE_ID", "11111");
    _repo.Delete(obj);
    _repo.Save();
```

I get this exception:

> {"An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner
>   exception for details."}

Inner exception:

> {"Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."}

StackTrace:

> at
>   System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.CreateCommand(DbModificationCommandTree
>   commandTree)    at
>   System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.CreateCommand(UpdateTranslator
>   translator, Dictionary`2 identifierValues)    at
>   System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator
>   translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2
>   identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)    at
>   System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager
>   stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)

I tested my repository class again MS SQL database it works good.

What can cause this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I remember seeing something  like this:

```
_context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity, EntityState.Modified);
```

1. Load/Attach entity
2. Flag it as changed/tracked
3. Delete/Remove from Context
4. Save

   MSDN Notes http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectstatemanager.aspx

related Post [ObjectContext tracking changes in Entity Framwwork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730140/objectcontext-tracking-changes-in-entity-framwwork)

For performance reasons you can load an object without change tracking

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are retrieving the object without using the ObjectContext.

Therefore, the loaded object is not attached to the context.

When you then try to delete it via the context, the current state of the entity is "detached", which is not valid for a delete operation.