# How do I to store original values EF4.0 Audit Trail

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I am trying to do an audit trail in ef4.0 and I am trying to store the original values my problem is that any reference i make to the entity will be saved upon save changes.how do i access the original values of entity after save changes called i been trying to use this method.

```
    public static object DeepCopy(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return null;
            Type type = obj.GetType();

            if (type.IsValueType || type == typeof(string))
            {
                return obj;
            }
            else if (type.IsArray)
            {
                Type elementType = Type.GetType(
                     type.FullName.Replace("[]", string.Empty));
                var array = obj as Array;
                Array copied = Array.CreateInstance(elementType, array.Length);
                for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
                {
                    copied.SetValue(DeepCopy(array.GetValue(i)), i);
                }
                return Convert.ChangeType(copied, obj.GetType());
            }
            else if (type.IsClass)
            {

                object toret = Activator.CreateInstance(obj.GetType());
                FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public |
                            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
                {
                    object fieldValue = field.GetValue(obj);
                    if (fieldValue == null)
                        continue;
                    field.SetValue(toret, DeepCopy(fieldValue));
                }
                return toret;
            }
            else
                throw new ArgumentException("Unknown type");
        }

            private void AddStatusHistoryRecord(string notes)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (absenceEntity.ess_absence_history == null)
                    {
                        if (statusHistory == null)
                            statusHistory = new List<AbsenceStatusHistoryList>();

                        statusHistory.Add(new AbsenceStatusHistoryList(userId, userName, 3, 3, DateTime.Now, notes));

                        EmployeeAbsenceStatusHistory history = new EmployeeAbsenceStatusHistory();
                        history.absence = absenceEntity;
                        history.history_xml = GetStatusHistoryXml();
                       if(isEdit  == false)
                            pamsContext.AddAbsenceStatusHistory(history);
                       if (isEdit == true)
                           grdStatusHistory.CurrentRow.Cells["Notes"].Value = notes;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (statusHistory == null)
                            GetStatusHistoryRecords();
                        if (isEdit == false) 
                            statusHistory.Add(new AbsenceStatusHistoryList(userId, userName, 3, 3, DateTime.Now, notes));
                        if (isEdit == true)
                            grdStatusHistory.CurrentRow.Cells["Notes"].Value = notes;

                        absenceEntity.ess_absence_history.history_xml = GetStatusHistoryXml();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ExceptionBox.Show("An error occurred in the AddStatusHistoryRecord method.", ex);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to access the changeTracker before Save.  I would expect that after a successful `SaveChanges` then all entities that were in state `modified` are subsequently in the state `unchanged`

See  https://stackoverflow.com/a/6730415/1347784 for objectContext access to change tracker.

A sample context Dump tool. That use DBContext not Objectcontext, so it would need Changing if you only have access ObjectContext. ef4.0 was only Objectcontext ?
in case it is of help...

```
 public static void ContextDumpTest(DbContext context)
    {

        Debug.WriteLine("=====Begin of Context Dump=======");
        var dbsetList = context.ChangeTracker.Entries();
        foreach (var dbEntityEntry in dbsetList)
        {

            Debug.WriteLine(dbEntityEntry.Entity.GetType().Name + " => " + dbEntityEntry.State);
            switch (dbEntityEntry.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Detached:
                case EntityState.Unchanged:
                case EntityState.Added:
                case EntityState.Modified:
                    WriteValuesPairs(dbEntityEntry);
                    break;
                case EntityState.Deleted:
                    WriteOriginalValues(dbEntityEntry);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("==========End of Entity======");
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("==========End of Context======");
    }
    private static void WriteValuesPairs(DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry)
    {
        foreach (var cv in dbEntityEntry.OriginalValues.PropertyNames)
        {
            if (dbEntityEntry.OriginalValues[cv] == null && dbEntityEntry.CurrentValues[cv] == null) {
                Debug.WriteLine(cv + " Unchanged: " + "null"); 
            }
            else 
            if  (dbEntityEntry.OriginalValues[cv] != null && dbEntityEntry.CurrentValues[cv] != null
                  &&  dbEntityEntry.OriginalValues[cv].Equals(dbEntityEntry.CurrentValues[cv]) ) {
                Debug.WriteLine(cv + " Unchanged: " + dbEntityEntry.OriginalValues[cv]);
            }
            else {
                Debug.WriteLine(cv + " Original= " + dbEntityEntry.OriginalValues[cv] + "-> New= " + dbEntityEntry.CurrentValues[cv]);    
            }


        }
    }
```